# Insert characters via CID in XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, characters

In LuaTeX, we can use `\CID` and `\UTF` in `luatexja-otf` to insert characters via their CIDs:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{luatexja-otf}
\setCJKmainfont{KozMinPr6N-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}
森\UTF{9DD7}外と内田百\UTF{9592}とが\UTF{9AD9}島屋に行く。

\CID{7652}飾区の\CID{13706}野家，\CID{1481}城市，葛西駅，高崎と\CID{8705}\UTF{FA11}
\end{document}
```

They are inherited from upTeX. So how to use CID-key to insert some character in XeTeX?

For Kozuka Mincho Pr6N, the glyph order is the same as CID order (Adobe Japan1-6). But other fonts may not use the same order, so `\XeTeXglyph` etc cannot be (at least, directly) used here.

Answer (score 2):

A proof of concept using the `cidmap` files in TeX Live.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho ProN}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\readCIDfile}{m}
 {
  \readcid_file:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\CID}{m}
 {
  \use:c { CID#1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\UTF}{m}
 {
  \symbol { \int_from_hex:n { #1 } }
 }

\ior_new:N \g_readcid_file_stream

\cs_new_protected:Nn \readcid_file:n
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g_readcid_file_stream { #1 }
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_readcid_file_stream
   {
    \__readcid_line:n { ##1 }
   }
 }


\cs_new_protected:Nn \__readcid_line:n
 {
  \__readcid_line_aux:w #1 \q_stop
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__readcid_line_aux:w #1 ~ #2 \q_stop
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { #2 }
   {
    \str_case_e:nnF { \str_range:nnn { #2 } { 1 } { 3 } }
     {
      {/un}{ \__readcid_def_uni:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
      {/Ja}{ \__readcid_def_japan:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
      {./n}{ }
     }
     { \__readcid_def:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__readcid_def:nn
 {
  \str_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { . }
   {
    \__readcid_def:w #1 - { #2 }
   }
   {
    \__readcid_def_do:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__readcid_def:w #1..#2 - #3
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnn { #1 } { #2 }
   {
    \__readcid_def_do:nn { ##1 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__readcid_def_do:nn
 {
  \cs_new:cpx {CID#1} { \UTF { #2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__readcid_def_uni:nn
 {
  \str_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { . }
   {
    \__readcid_def_uni_multi:w #1 - { #2 }
   }
   {
    \__readcid_def_uni_do:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__readcid_def_uni_multi:w #1..#2 - #3
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnn { #1 } { #2 }
   {
    \__readcid_def_uni_do:nn { ##1 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__readcid_def_uni_do:nn
 {
  \cs_new:cpx {CID#1} { \UTF { \str_range:nnn { #2 } { 5 } { 8 } } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__readcid_def_japan:nn
 {
  \str_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { . }
   {
    \__readcid_def_japan_multi:w #1 - { #2 }
   }
   {
    \__readcid_def_japan_do:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__readcid_def_japan_multi:w #1..#2 - #3
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnn { #1 } { #2 }
   {
    \__readcid_def_japan_do:nn { ##1 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__readcid_def_japan_do:nn
 {
  \cs_new:cpx {CID#1} { \CID { \__readcid_japan_strip:w #2 \q_stop } }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__readcid_japan_strip:w #1.#2.#3 \q_stop { #2 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\readCIDfile{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/cid/fontforge/Adobe-Japan1-6.cidmap}

\begin{document}

森\UTF{9DD7}外と内田百\UTF{9592}とが\UTF{9AD9}島屋に行く。

森鷗外と内田百閒とが髙島屋に行く。

\CID{7652}飾区の\CID{13706}野家，\CID{1481}城市，葛西駅，高崎と\CID{8705}\UTF{FA11}

\CID{7652}飾区の野家，葛城市，葛西駅，高崎と髙﨑

\end{document}
```

There is no CID 7652, as far as I can see in Adobe-Japan1-6.

[image]

Some explanations: the first in the `.cidmap` line contains the number of entries and we don't need it. The other lines have the form

```
<CID> <translation>
```

or

```
<CID>..<CID> <translation>
```

for multiple entries pointing to the same UTF character.

Many of the translations are just a Unicode code point in hexadecimal, others have the form

```
/uni<pqrs>.<other specs>
```

or

```
/Japan1.<CID>.<other specs>
```

so these macros strip `/uni` and the part from the period on. In the Unicode or `/uni` cases, I define `\CID<CID>` to do `\UTF{<code>}`. Otherwise `\CID<CID>` does `\CID{<CID>}`.

The macro `\CID{<number>}` expands to `\CID<number>` (define via the analog of `\csname...\endcsname`).

A full specification of the `.cidmap` files might improve the translation.

Comment: The point is that several CIDs may map to a single Unicode code point. Here, cid1481 and cid7652 both map to U+845B 葛, but they are different glyphs (look different). That's why I need to use CID rather than UTF.

Comment: @stone-zeng I said it is a proof of concept.